# i get an error in the appDelegate?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

when am trying to change the code of a to do list app from preCoreData to coreData.

i get this error:

**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'**

[this is the preCoreData app link](https://github.com/BitFountain/TaskIt-PreCoreData)

[this is the CoreData app link](https://github.com/BitFountain/TaskIt-WithCoreData)

Comment: Most people want to help, however they may not want to download your entire project, can you update your question with the code you're using? - From the looks of it, you need to specify the entity in your fetch request

Comment: how  i know the infected part to upload it ... Xcode didn't show any error

Comment: I would think it's your fetch request

Answer (score 0):

the entity name missing in my code

**my code with error**

```
 func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
```

> let fetchRequest =  NSFetchRequest()

```
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    let completedDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "completed", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [completedDescriptor, sortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequest
}
```

**my code without error**

```
 func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
```

> let fetchRequest =  NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TaskModel")

```
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    let completedDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "completed", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [completedDescriptor, sortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequest
}
```